# AWS - Unable to connect to mongo in Lightsail from Lambda

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lightsail

The following are the two key points.

- I have a mongo instance deployed in AWS Lightsail.
- I have set of lambda functions(written in python) which need to communicate with this particular DB

But every time I run the function (triggered from API Gateway) it times out.

The following are the things I have tried with no luck:

- Added VPCExecution IAM role to Lambda.
- Tried opening the Lightsail instance to the public(0.0.0.0), in which communication happens(obviously), but is definitely not a recommended solution
- Tried setting up a NAT Gateway with a static IP and whitelisting it in Lightsail's firewall. This also works but I cannot afford the cost.
- Tried enabling the VPC Peering from Lighsail's account panel. Still no luck. (This is where I was hoping it to work)

Is there anything I'm missing. I really don't need to go towards EC2. But if you can offer any advice that results in the same cost, that'd be great.

PS: I am able to connect to the instance after whitelisting my Public IP.

I really need help with this. Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How *are* you able to connect to the database?

Comment: From my local machine. As stated above, included my IP in the inbound rules of the instance. Now since, lambda doesn't have a static IP, there's no way to whitelist a single IP/CIDR.

Comment: Can lambda connect with 0.0.0.0 in firewall rules?

Comment: Yes. It is able to do that.

Comment: That is important information.

Comment: Lightsail instances have a public IP address and a private IP address.  To use VPC peering, you have to make the connection using the *private* address.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, VPC peering is happening through Private CIDR only. I verified both for Requester and Acceptor CIDR. Does the lambda need to be inside the default VPC to work?

Comment: @Surya yes, it does need to be in the default VPC.  Unless something has changed, that's the only VPC that can be peered with Lightsail and peering isn't transitive.  Then, you need to access the Lightsale instance from the Lambda function *using* the Lightsail instance's private IP address.